# replace the "switch store" by a navigation bar to select the desired store

Tags: multistore, ce-1.9.0.1, scope-switcher

Here is my installation, 1 website (1 domain) with 2 Each store and store view. Note that I am not coding or programmer, which explains my question:

I would like to replace the "switch store" by a navigation bar to select the desired store, as these 2 website:

```
http://www.diapers.com

http://www.gap.com/
```

Can you tell me what I should do and where to start?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Chip,magento have provide `two magento site with one magento install`.
You need t`o ailse two site domain in one share hosting`.

Here,you have  set difference category each site:
more details:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-multi-site-multi-domain-setup
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/overview-how-multiple-websites-stores-work/

Comment: Thank you for your help Amit Bera,

The multi-store setup is already done. Here what I want to do is a navigation bar for my frontend I would put up my header and where my customers need only click on the link of the store in which he traveling on wheels to buy be redirected. This bar will replace the existing store swich, as the two previously mentioned links.

Comment: got it.............